Anaconda: Unable to install Kivy 2.3
I want to install Kivy to my Anaconda tutorialEnv.
According to https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-conda
I have used conda install kivy -c conda-forge command.
But i got an error.
Before Kivy library, i had only installed pip install Django==5.1.3 without a problem.
After that when i try to install Kivy, i have below error.
Error:
---------- -------
pip        24.2
setuptools 75.1.0
wheel      0.44.0

(tutorialEnv) C:\Users\mecra\OneDrive\Desktop\Python>pip install Django==5.1.3
Collecting Django==5.1.3
  Downloading Django-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.8.1 (from Django==5.1.3)
  Using cached asgiref-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.3 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.3.1 (from Django==5.1.3)
  Using cached sqlparse-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting tzdata (from Django==5.1.3)
  Using cached tzdata-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Downloading Django-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.3/8.3 MB 408.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached asgiref-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Using cached sqlparse-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Using cached tzdata-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (346 kB)
Installing collected packages: tzdata, sqlparse, asgiref, Django
Successfully installed Django-5.1.3 asgiref-3.8.1 sqlparse-0.5.1 tzdata-2024.2

(tutorialEnv) C:\Users\mecra\OneDrive\Desktop\Python>pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
asgiref    3.8.1
Django     5.1.3
pip        24.2
setuptools 75.1.0
sqlparse   0.5.1
tzdata     2024.2
wheel      0.44.0

(tutorialEnv) C:\Users\mecra\OneDrive\Desktop\Python>conda install kivy -c conda-forge
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package kivy-1.10.1-py27h7bc4a79_2 requires python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ kivy is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ kivy [1.10.1|1.11.0|1.11.1] would require
│  │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ kivy 1.10.1 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ kivy [1.10.1|1.11.0|1.11.1|2.0.0|2.0.0rc4] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ kivy [1.10.1|1.11.0|...|2.1.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ kivy [1.11.1|2.0.0|...|2.3.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ kivy [2.0.0|2.1.0|2.2.0|2.2.1|2.3.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ kivy [2.0.0|2.0.0rc4|...|2.3.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ kivy [2.2.1|2.3.0] would require
│     └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

How can i fix this problem?
Thanks

I would also recommend to install django with conda, not pip

You need to downgrade to Python 3.11 as suggested in the error message for Kivy 2.3 as it conflicts with Python 3.12
conda install python=3.11

Then reinstall Kivy 2.3

it worked. Thanks very much
